# How can we 'attach' animation nodes to objects?

Tags: animation-nodes, linked-data, append

I want to find a way to attach the animation-node tree with a collection or an object.  So that when I link/append the collection to other scene, the animation node tree also comes with it and functions.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. As far I know, there is no option/feature in blender 2.80/2.81 to make a collection for Node-Trees of any kind.

Comment: can the node tree be attached in an object?

Comment: There is no option in the current version of Animation Nodes to attach a node-tree with an object.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification.